# Find / encode version number into a device driver that is statically compiled into the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I believe that the MODULE_VERSION does not work if the driver is statically compiled into the kernel. The version number was no where to be seen in the sysfs. the modinfo does not work as its not a loaded module.
So Whats the best way for to wither get the MODULE_VERSION of this driver or encode version number in the driver. Is there a standard way of doing this or should I simply use sysfs?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no much sense to have a module version for in tree modules. Otherwise it is kept is special section called `__modver`.

```
$ objdump -h ~/prj/TMP/out/mfld/vmlinux -j __modver
/home/andy/prj/TMP/out/mfld/vmlinux:     file format elf32-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
 12 __modver      00000c40  c1a003c0  01a003c0  00a013c0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

It contains pointers to corresponding structures defined in `include/linux/module.h` in macro `MODULE_VERSION`.

Comment: It makes sense when you are developing as well as deploying different versions at different OEMs.  I developed over 4 versions of the driver and all of them are in different devices. I cant make out which version is running in which.

Comment: `uname -a` usually shows kernel version. If version was altered the hash is added. So, you always know what the version is. *Linux version 4.0.0-rc3-next-20150313+ #123 SMP Fri Mar 13 15:54:01 EET 2015*

Comment: I mean the driver version. not kernel version. I want to know my driver version which is inside a vmlinux that was not built by me.

Comment: You meant third party driver, right? We usually don't care about them. If they provide version, then it's okay, otherwise, you will not know if you not a person who install that driver. In case of in-tree driver you always know what is the version. Try to figure it out.

Comment: That third party is me. I provide the drivers to the OEMs and sometimes change it as per their requirmeents. I need someway of tracking the version. I gave new releases to the vendors and they still manged to use the old ones. So I want some way of knowing my driver version on a deployed system where my driver is not a kernel module but part of the vmlinux

Comment: Then like I said we don't care, you are on your own. The easiest way to you to get module version is just print it at `->init()` or `->probe()` stage. If you don't like the approach (which might be unreliable) you can go through the section in the binary and get it.